# How to zip subfolders individually with tar & pigz?

Tags: zip, tar

I want to zip all sub-child folders to tar.gz files separately? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Ubuntu 18

```
for dir in ./*; do
    (cd "$dir" &&  tar --use-compress-program="pigz -k " -cvf /path-to-your/target-folder/${dir}.tar.gz .)
done
```

You should save those commands to a .sh file for later use.